# why invalidate() cannot be called from outside an object?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, object, view

I am implementing custom view in android studio using java.In the process i have to update value to custom object creted from custom view.I am unable to do so.Here is my sample code:
custom view->

```
public class simpleclass extends View{
private simple_line line;

constructors[..
line=new simple_line(0);
];

public void update_line(float up_val){
line.set_xval=up_val;
}

onmeasuremethod[..];
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){line.draw_line(canvas); }

private class simple_line{
 private Paint mpaint;
 private float xval;

 public simple_line(float val){
 xval=val;
 mpaint=new Paint();
 mpaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
 mpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 mpaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
 }

 public void set_xval(float val){
     this.xval=val;
     invalidate();
 }
 public float get_xval(){
     return xval;
 }
 public draw_line(Canvas canvas){
     Path mypath=new Path();
     mypath.moveTo(getwidth/2+xval,0);
     mypath.lineTo(getwidth/2+xval,getHeight);
     mypath.close();
     canvas.drawPath(mypath,mpaint);
  }
 }
}
```

Main activity->

```
simple_object=new simpleclass(this);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         simple_object.update_line(100);
     }
});
```

update on button press don't work when object(simple_object) is created but would work after object is not created.

why is it so?
how to update when after object is created?

Comment: Can you make question more clear and add some more code what you tried ?

Comment: Start by replacing `simple_object.void update_line(100);` with `simple_object.update_line(100);`. There is no reason to specify the return type when calling an implemented method. Moreover, it should not work as you're making a static call to a non-static method : you should instanciate simple_object in your Activity.

Comment: simple_object is an instance of class simpleclass.How to instantiate an object?